# How can I find the best place to fit a label inside a polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, polygon, esri

The polygon may or may not be convex and cannot be rotated.
The label is a rectangle that also cannot be rotated.
I need the center of the biggest zone for placing the center of the label.

(Ideally would be to get a polygon of possible placements for the center of the label. That would allow disjointedly placing labels on overlapping polygons, but it would be too much...)

I'm using a Geometry Service (ESRI) which can test if a geometry (rectangle, polygon, etc) is inside another polygon (The irregular polygon.)

[image: Not a very good solution]

Comment: Maybe center it on the [maximum circle inside a non-convex polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279478/maximum-circle-inside-a-non-convex-polygon).

Comment: That is an interesting point, and I'm going to investigate.

Yet, from the very start it has a flaw: the label may be very wide and not so high, and may fit better in an area where the biggest circle does not fit!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the solution was simple:

1. Create four polygons by translating the original one with w, -w, h, -h
   where w and h are the semi-width and semi-height of the label.
2. Intersect those four polygons.
3. if the intersection is null - the label won't fit in the polygon. Exit.
4. All points inside the intersection satisfy the requirement: place the center of the label in one of those points.
   [image]