# Hand palm segmentation: alternatives to cv2.erode

Tags: opencv, time, image-segmentation

I am trying to segment the center of the hand palm using its binary image (mask) and applying an erode with a quite big kernel. This takes to much time to process.

I am looking for an alternative that takes less time.

Comment: Try a distance transform as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648903/1377097).

Answer (score 0):

You can also find "skeleton" of the image. OpenCV function: "cv.ximgproc.thinning()"

Scikit-Image function: "skimage.morphology.skeletonize()"

Comment: seems like an interesting approach. Thanks!