# How could we calculate the diameter of the largest circle inside a regular polygon?

Tags: java, math, geometry, int, rounding

I have been training with the following programming exercise: [Circles in Polygons](https://www.codewars.com/kata/circles-in-polygons/train/java). The statement is:

> You are the owner of a box making company.
>
> Your company can produce any equal sided polygon box, but plenty of
>   your customers want to transport circular objects in these boxes.
>   Circles are a very common shape in the consumer industry. Tin cans,
>   glasses, tyres and CD's are a few examples of these.
>
> As a result you decide to add this information on your boxes: The
>   largest (diameter) circular object that can fit into a given box.

I have found the following formula:
[image]

Taken from: https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonincircle.html

So to calculate the diameter of the largest incircle we have:

sideLength / tan(180/numberOfSides)

I have written the following code:

```
public class Polygon {
    int sides;
    int sideLength;

    public Polygon(int sides, int sideLength) {
        this.sides = sides;
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
    }

    public double circleDiameter /**/(){
      double div = Math.toRadians(180/sides);
      System.out.println("div: "+div);
      double den = Math.tan(div);
      System.out.println("den: "+den);
      double diameter = sideLength / den;
      System.out.println("diameter: "+diameter);
      return diameter;
    }

}
```

However I wonder why it does fail one test and passes two of them. Here are the test, extracted from the exercise:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PolygonTest {

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        //Square with sides of 5 units
        Polygon poly=new Polygon(4, 5);
        assertEquals("5.000", String.format("%.3f", poly.circleDiameter()));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        //Octagon with sides of 9 units
        Polygon poly=new Polygon(8, 9);
        assertEquals("21.728", String.format("%.3f", poly.circleDiameter()));
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        //Triangle with sides of 4 units
        Polygon poly=new Polygon(3, 4);
        assertEquals("2.309", String.format("%.3f", poly.circleDiameter()));
    }
}
```

And our code fails the Octagon test. The trace is:

```
div: 0.3839724354387525
den: 0.4040262258351568
diameter: 22.275781680746665
expected:<2[1.728]> but was:<2[2.276]>
```

Why does the code give this result? I have thought that there could be a rounding error. However it is so big that I think it is the formula the one which is wrong.

I have also read:

- [Largest circle inside a non-convex polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279478/largest-circle-inside-a-non-convex-polygon)
- [Is there a simple algorithm for calculating the maximum inscribed circle into a convex polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953623/is-there-a-simple-algorithm-for-calculating-the-maximum-inscribed-circle-into-a?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `sideLength / tan(180/numberOfSides)` is missing the factor of 2 in the denominator.  According to the formula you posted, that should be `sideLength / (2 * tan(180/numberOfSides))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double div = Math.toRadians(180/sides);
```

When `sides` is 8 the result should be 22.5, but because both 180 and `sides` are integers the calculation is done using integer math, yielding 22.

Change one or both operands to doubles to ensure there's no inadvertent rounding:

```
double div = Math.toRadians(180.0/sides);
```